# Dynamically Build Menu - Two Arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays...

```
$Name = array(a, b, c, d);
$Value = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I want to dynamically build a menu where I would assign, in order, Name to equal Value? Example: Result would be `a=1,b=2,c=3` etc.,

Final Result of Menu...

```
<select name="Menu">
   <option value="1">a</option>
   <option value="2">b</option>
   <option value="3">c</option>
   <option value="4">d</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You mean, generating a select tag with the help of two arrays. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$Name = array(a, b, c, d);
$Value = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$c = array_combine($Name, $Value);
echo "<select name=\"Menu\">\n";
foreach($c as $k=>$v){
    echo "<option value=\"$k\">$v</option>\n";
}
echo "<select>\n";
?>
```

**[codepad example](http://codepad.org/ZLyJdgvQ)**

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure both arrays are the same lenght then you can do

```
echo '<select name="Menu">';

foreach($name as $key=>$val){
 echo '<option value="'.$Value['key'].'">'.$val.'</option>'
}

echo '</select>';
```

It'd be better if it was an associative array of the form:`array('name1'=>'value1','name2'=>'value2','name3'=>'value3')`